# how read/write among 4000 values with 50 concurrent threads in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multithreading, thread-safety

I've got a pool of 4000 measurements that i need to access (read or write) from 50 simultaneous threads, under the following conditions :

- Many threads should be able to read the same measurement at the same time
- if a thread tries to read a measurement while it is being updated by another thread, it should read a value (it doesn't matter if it's the former value or the new one)
- if several threads try to update the same measurement at the same time, this measurement should be updated with the value given by one of the threads (the values from the other threads will be lost)

using 1 variable for each measurement seems to work well:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var XXXX1 : Float!
    var XXXX2 : Float!
    ....
}
```

but unfortunately for 4000 variables the compiler takes hours to compile (see [Unable to compile swift xcode project with 4000 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64159739/unable-to-compile-swift-xcode-project-with-4000-variables) which was closed)

I was advised to use some kind of "thread safe" array with 4000 values, but i fear this won't solve the problem. i understand that such a solution would lock the whole array each time a value is updated, making the array unreadable and unwritable at the same time by the other threads.

Comment: Your description sounds like you don't care about race conditions. In that case you could just try to use a regular array, without thread-safe locks? Other approach would be to just group your variables into some container objects - so, for instance, your ViewController would contain 20 variables, each being an object that contains 20 measurements

Comment: i tried that but then i get random EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i update the array for example with self.myarray[0] = mynewvalue

Comment: i'm going to try your suggested second approach

Comment: @Gogo123 What do you mean by "I get random EXC_BAD_ACCESS" - How did you configure that array? Can you show ?

Comment: Can you show how are you accessing the array to get EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using an array of objects of this subclass :

```
class ValueContainer : NSObject {
    var value : Float!
    
    init(_ value: Float) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

```
self.myValues = [ValueContainer]()
```

I fill the array myvalues with 4000 "ValueContainer" at start.
Then I read/write in all threads :

```
self.myValues[i].value = ...
```

this doesn't modify the array thus avoid thread issues